# Set encoding in curl command in powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, encoding, utf-8

I have curl command stored in variable ($command). The command looks like this:

```
curl -F "login=xxx" -F "password=xxx" "title=Some title" -F "img=@/path/to/image" https://example.com/api/import
```

Then i execute the command:

```
Invoke-Expression ($command)
```

Everything is fine unless title contains special characters like "č,š,ý..." because server expects UTF8 encoded parameters. In such case special characters are replaced with questionmarks on the website.

I tried setting `[Console]::OutputEncoding` and `$OutputEncoding` to UTF8 but it didn't solve the problem.When i run the command on linux (ubuntu) everything is fine because it uses UTF8 as default encoding, so i rewrote the script to bash to get the job done. But i'm still wondering if it's possible in powershell somehow. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Curious why you'd use curl instead of [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)? Or even apparently there's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849901.aspx) in v3+ too.

Comment: Thanks for advice, i found example using curl in API documenatation so i used it. I didn't know about [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Settting `[Console]::OutputEncoding` works for me. Are you sure you're setting it correctly?

```
C:\PS> [console]::OutputEncoding = [text.encoding]::UTF8
C:\PS> echoargs "title=č,š,ý"
Arg 0 is <title=č,š,ý>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  title=č,š,ý
```

Echoargs is a tool from [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I set the encoding exactly like you did. Echoargs works fine (even without setting [console]::OutputEncoding), but after curl the special characters are still replaced with questionmarks on website.